# How to split documents into training set and test set?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

I am trying to build a classification model. I have 1000 text documents in local folder. I want to divide them into training set and test set with a split ratio of 70:30(70 -> Training and 30 -> Test)  What is the better approach to do so? I am using python.

---

I wanted a approach programatically to split the training set and test set. First to read the files in local directory. Second, to build a list of those files and shuffle them. Thirdly to split them into a training set and test set.

I tried a few ways by using built in python keywords and functions only to fail. Lastly I got the idea of approaching it. Also Cross-validation is a good option to be considered for the building general classification models.

Comment: Scikit learn have many functions available to do what you want with examples. Search the net and post here if you find any difficulties in applying them

Comment: Whats wrong with the question? why members are downvoting the question?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for taking opinions. It's for programming. You are simply asking without showing any effort.

Comment: @VivekKumar I already prepared tf-idf for these documents. The question I asked is one of my step on the small project. I understand its programming, which I have done. I have seen descriptions like the answer here below on other questions. I just wanted to know the best practices when it comes to splitting documents. FYI, I already written the code before asking the question.

Comment: The answer here below helped me optimize it. I am grateful to it. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not sure *exactly* what you're after, so I'll try to be comprehensive. There will be a few steps:

1. Get a list of the files
2. Randomize the files
3. Split files into training and testing sets
4. Do the thing

## 1. Get a list of the files

Let's assume that your files all have the extension `.data` and they're all in the folder `/ml/data/`. What we want to do is get a list of all of these files. This is done simply with the `os` module. I'm assuming you have no subdirectories; this would change if there were.

```
import os

def get_file_list_from_dir(datadir):
    all_files = os.listdir(os.path.abspath(datadir))
    data_files = list(filter(lambda file: file.endswith('.data'), all_files))
    return data_files
```

So if we were to call `get_file_list_from_dir('/ml/data')`, we would get back a list of all the `.data` files in that directory (equivalent in the shell to the glob `/ml/data/*.data`).

## 2. Randomize the files

We don't want the sampling to be predictable, as that is considered a poor way to train an ML classifier.

```
from random import shuffle

def randomize_files(file_list):
    shuffle(file_list)
```

Note that `random.shuffle` performs an *in-place* shuffling, so it modifies the existing list. (Of course this function is rather silly since you could just call `shuffle` instead of `randomize_files`; you can write this into another function to make it make more sense.)

## 3. Split files into training and testing sets

I'll assume a 70:30 ratio instead of any specific number of documents. So:

```
from math import floor

def get_training_and_testing_sets(file_list):
    split = 0.7
    split_index = floor(len(file_list) * split)
    training = file_list[:split_index]
    testing = file_list[split_index:]
    return training, testing
```

## 4. Do the thing

This is the step where you open each file and do your training and testing. I'll leave this to you!

---

## Cross-Validation

Out of curiosity, have you considered using [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics))? This is a method of splitting your data so that you use every document for training and testing. You can customize how many documents are used for training in each "fold". I could go more into depth on this if you like, but I won't if you don't want to do it.

Edit: Alright, since you requested I will explain this a little bit more.

So we have a 1000-document set of data. The idea of cross-validation is that you can use *all* of it for both training and testing — just not at once. We split the dataset into what we call "folds". The number of folds determines the size of the training and testing sets at any given point in time.

Let's say we want a 10-fold cross-validation system. This means that the training and testing algorithms will run ten times. The first time will train on documents 1-100 and test on 101-1000. The second fold will train on 101-200 and test on 1-100 and 201-1000.

If we did, say, a 40-fold CV system, the first fold would train on document 1-25 and test on 26-1000, the second fold would train on 26-40 and test on 1-25 and 51-1000, and on.

To implement such a system, we would still need to do steps (1) and (2) from above, but step (3) would be different. Instead of splitting into just two sets (one for training, one for testing), we could turn the function into a [*generator*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) — a function which we can iterate through like a list.

```
def cross_validate(data_files, folds):
    if len(data_files) % folds != 0:
        raise ValueError(
            "invalid number of folds ({}) for the number of "
            "documents ({})".format(folds, len(data_files))
        )
    fold_size = len(data_files) // folds
    for split_index in range(0, len(data_files), fold_size):
        training = data_files[split_index:split_index + fold_size]
        testing = data_files[:split_index] + data_files[split_index + fold_size:]
        yield training, testing
```

That `yield` keyword at the end is what makes this a generator. To use it, you would use it like so:

```
def ml_function(datadir, num_folds):
    data_files = get_file_list_from_dir(datadir)
    randomize_files(data_files)
    for train_set, test_set in cross_validate(data_files, num_folds):
        do_ml_training(train_set)
        do_ml_testing(test_set)
```

Again, it's up to you to implement the actual functionality of your ML system.

As a disclaimer, I'm no expert by any means, haha. But let me know if you have any questions about anything I've written here!

Comment: I want to split 1000 text documents (.txt) into training and test set for implementing tf-idf and apply a algo in order to build a classification model. The one that will classify docs into two separate classes acc to my objective.

Comment: Yes I have considered Cross-validation. But as a beginner I thought not to go for it. I request you to explain that as well. Please.

Comment: @BhabaniMohapatra I have updated the bottom portion to explain how you might do some cross-validation. The specifics are up to you, but what I've written should help you to load your data appropriately. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: FWIW, using `dir` as a parameter in your `get_file_list_from_dir` function isn't good practice, as `dir` is a Python built-in function. Maybe try something like `directory` instead.

Comment: @not_a_robot right you are! I'm usually much better about that, but was in a hurry earlier, haha. Updated now; thank you! :)

Comment: @PierceDarragh Went through your code, I am currently implementing      tf-idf. I have to now alter my code's a bit inorder to implement cross-validation. I will update you.

Comment: The k-fold cross validation is actually explained in reverse order. Each time, one of the k subsets is used as the test set and the other k-1 subsets are put together to form a training set.

Answer (score 4):

that's quite simple if you use numpy, first load the documents and make them a numpy array, and then:

```
import numpy as np

docs = np.array([
    'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five',
    'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten',
    ])

idx = np.hstack((np.ones(7), np.zeros(3))) # generate indices
np.random.shuffle(idx) # shuffle to make training data and test data random

train = docs[idx == 1]
test = docs[idx == 0]

print(train)
print(test)
```

the result:

```
['one' 'two' 'three' 'six' 'eight' 'nine' 'ten']
['four' 'five' 'seven']
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make a list of the filenames using `os.listdir()`. Use `collections.shuffle()` to shuffle the list, and then `training_files = filenames[:700]` and `testing_files = filenames[700:]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use train_test_split method provided by sklearn. See documentation here:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html