# How to copy a set percentage of files into a directory

Tags: python

I have to define a function:

```
def split_data(SOURCE, TRAINING, TESTING, SPLIT_SIZE):
```

The function is supposed to copy files from a source directory to TRAINING AND TESTING given a split size. It cannot copy files which are of 0 size and they should be shuffled. I managed to define some function, but it doesn't copy all of the files in a directory, just one! I just don't know how to define it so that it takes the split_size into account.

```
def split_data(SOURCE, TRAINING, TESTING, SPLIT_SIZE):
    source_files = [f for f in os.listdir(SOURCE) if os.path.getsize(os.path.join(SOURCE, f)) > 0]
    random.shuffle(source_files)
    
  #here we've got the total number of files in cats/dogs parent folders
    total = len(source_files)
    
    to_training = source_files[0: int(total * split_size)]
    to_test = source_files[int(total * split_size):]
        
            
    for file_name in to_training:
        full_file_name = os.path.join(SOURCE, file_name)
    if os.path.isfile(full_file_name):
        shutil.copy(full_file_name, TRAINING)
    for file_name in to_test:
        full_file_name = os.path.join(SOURCE, file_name)
    if os.path.isfile(full_file_name):
        shutil.copy(full_file_name, TESTING)
```

How should I tweak this function so that it takes split_size and copies the files accordingly (eg. if split size is 0.9, 90% of the files go to training directory and the rest to testing?

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471570/how-to-split-documents-into-training-set-and-test-set

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to nest the copy function in the for loop, otherwise only the last file in the list will be copied:

```
for file_name in to_training:
    full_file_name = os.path.join(SOURCE, file_name)
    if os.path.isfile(full_file_name):
        shutil.copy(full_file_name, TRAINING)
for file_name in to_test:
    full_file_name = os.path.join(SOURCE, file_name)
    if os.path.isfile(full_file_name):
        shutil.copy(full_file_name, TESTING)
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! IT WORKS! At first I couldn't even notice what you've changed! <3

Comment: You're welcome! Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer to close the question.